# Group by customer and calculate sum in SQL and return the top 15

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want Group by customer and sum CuryDocBal and return the top 15 customers after grouping
My current code only returns 15 rows. For example, I want Morton Salt Company's totals to be summed and represent 1 row.

```
   select top 15 a.Name ,d.CuryDocBal
   from
   ARDoc d 
   inner join 
   [AR_Balances] b 
    on d.CpnyID = b.CpnyID
  inner join [SIVSYS].[dbo].[Company] c
  on b.CpnyID = c.CpnyID
  inner join Customer a
  on d.CustId = a.Custid
  
  --DocType = 'IN'
   where 
 d.dueDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, -21, cast(getdate() as date)) and dateadd(day, 7, cast(getdate() as date))

  and CuryDocBal <> 0
 
 group  by a.Name ,
   d.CuryDocBal
   order by   d.CuryDocBal desc;
```

[image: QueryResults]

Answer (score 0):

you need  sum()

```
    select top 15 a.Name, d.DueDate, sum(d.CuryDocBal) curyDocBal ,d.RefNbr, d.BatNbr,
       b.CpnyID
         ,c.CpnyName
         from 
       ARDoc d 
       inner join 
       [AR_Balances] b 
        on d.CpnyID = b.CpnyID
      inner join [SIVSYS].[dbo].[Company] c
      on b.CpnyID = c.CpnyID
      inner join Customer a
      on d.CustId = a.Custid
      
      --DocType = 'IN'
       where 
     d.dueDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, -21, cast(getdate() as date)) and dateadd(day, 7, cast(getdate() as date))
    --  and d.dueDate < dateadd(day, 7, cast(getdate() as date))
     --  (DueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, +7, GETDATE()) 
        --or
        --DueDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-21, GETDATE()) AND  GETDATE())
      and CuryDocBal <> 0
     
     group  by a.Name, d.DueDate,
       d.CuryDocBal, b.CpnyID
         ,c.CpnyName, d.RefNbr, d.BatNbr
       order by   d.CuryDocBal desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `CuryDocBal` from the `group by` and sum it instead.

```sql
select top 15
    a.Name,
    TotalCuryDocBal = sum(d.CuryDocBal)
from ARDoc d 
inner join [AR_Balances] b on d.CpnyID = b.CpnyID
inner join [SIVSYS].[dbo].[Company] c on b.CpnyID = c.CpnyID
inner join Customer a on d.CustId = a.Custid
  
  --DocType = 'IN'
where
  d.dueDate BETWEEN dateadd(day, -21, cast(getdate() as date)) and dateadd(day, 7, cast(getdate() as date))

  and CuryDocBal <> 0
 
group  by a.Name
order by TotalCuryDocBal desc;
```